# Trying to add two values on the same line using a php loop in a HTML form.

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display two seperate items on the same line in a HTML form using a PHP loop to auto populate it. This is the PHP/HTML form:

```
           <select class="form-control" name="list" title="pick a type">
              <?php if(count($postOpts)) { ?>
              <?php foreach($postOpts as $row) { ?>
              <option value="<?= $row["name"] ?>"><?= $row["price"] ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <option value="<?= $post->getDefaultPrice() ?>"><?= "Default Shipping Option - $".$post->getDefaultPrice() ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
           </select>
```

I can have either the price or the name displaying, but not both on the same line.

Can anyone help?

Comment: <option value="<?= $row["name"] ?>"><?= $row["price"] ?></option>

Comment: like e.g.: <option value="<?= $row["name"] ?>"><?= $row["name"] . $row["price"] ?></option>

Answer (score 1):

May be try this,

```
<option value="<?= $row["name"] ?>"><?= $row["name"] ."( $".$row["price"].")" ?></option>
```

Comment: Sure:) Glad it helped you.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Bhai, full traffic jam in silkboard. :D Without accepting, where he went. People answering this question as OP didn't got right answer.

Answer (score 0):

check the argument on here

`if(count($postOpts)) {`

should be

```
empty($postOpts)


<select class="form-control" name="list" title="pick a type">
  <?php 
  if(empty($postOpts)) { 
       foreach($postOpts as $row) 
       { 
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row["name"] ?>">
                <?php echo $row["price"] ?>
            </option>
      <?php 
        } 
    } else { 
        ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $post->getDefaultPrice() ?>"> 
            <?php echo "Default Shipping Option - $".$post->getDefaultPrice() ?>
          </option>
      <?php 
    } 
  ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace  `<option value="<?= $row["name"] ?>"><?= $row["price"] ?></option>` with `<option value="<?= $row['name'] ?>"><?= $row['price'] ?></option>` and let me know what you are getting now ?
You need to use single quote inside double quote or vice versa.